# Pegar a quantia de casas decimais de um double (Java)

Tags: java, javafx

pra contextualizar: tem um input com um textfield do javafx, aí tem uma label que aparece esse número digitado pelo usuário. se o usuário digita 1 eu quero que apareça só o 1, se o usuário digita 1.1 eu quero que apareça "1,1", e se digitar 1.111, que apareça "1,111", assim por diante... se eu usar o método do String.format(%.2f, valor) quando o usuário digita 1 aparece 1,00 e eu não quero isso, eu quero que só apareça a quantia de casas decimais que o usuário digitar

aí eu tava pensando em fazer assim:

```
int casas = (quantia de casas decimais);
String cd = "%." + casas + "f";
ai = String.format(cd, a)
```

no caso a variável "ai" é uma string e a variável "a" é um double, ambos são o input do campo pra inserir o valor a...

o que eu queria saber é se tem como eu conseguir o quantia de casas decimais do input... tipo se o número for 12.838 eu quero uma variável que fique com valor 3 que é a quantia de casas decimais desse double

se essa minha ideia for meio estranha existe algum outro método mais facil pra fazer isso?

e se ficou meio confuso, desculpa, primeira vez utilizando esse site e eu sou meio iniciante em java

Answer (score -1):

já consegui resolver, ficou assim:

```
String ai = valA.getText();
double restoa = a - Math.floor(a);

if (restoa != 0f){
            
    String[] result = ai.split("\\.");
    int casas = (int) result[1].length();
    String cd = "%." + casas + "f";
    ai = String.format(cd, a);
            
}
```

valA é o TextField do valor a

ele pega a string, separa em duas partes (antes e depois do ponto), e registra o comprimento depois do ponto

aí ele pega esse valor e coloca no delimitador de casas decimais

no fim o label fica só as casas decimais que foram digitadas

obrigado, de nada

Comment: Não precisa de nada disso, basta usar `NumberFormat` e pronto: https://ideone.com/kz44AN

Comment: mas aí ele fica só com 3 casas depois da virgula

Comment: Basta mudar o máximo de casas decimais: `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(20);` (faça isso antes de chamar `df.format`) e claro, ajuste a quantidade máxima de casas para o seu caso

Comment: obrigado :), mas tem um jeito que não fique separando os milhares/milhões? eu desejo que a única separação que aparece seja a dos decimais

Comment: Dica: sempre consulte a documentação de tudo que for usar. A resposta está aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setGroupingUsed-boolean-

Comment: muito obrigado :)